# QAbstractItemModel batch remove with many parents

Tags: qt, pyqt, qabstractitemmodel

I need to remove a lot of rows from a large tree model.
The problem is that the model contains many parent-indexes.
So I'll need to call beginRemoveRows too many times, making it way too slow.

Is it possible to do a batch remove of many rows which each has a different parent, and avoid having the view update on each remove.
I want to avoid beginResetModel, as it resets the entire view.

Comment: beginResetModel is the only solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try disable the updates on the widget while it's changing. Use setUpdatesEnabled false to remove the rows and set to true after it.

Comment: It will only prevent repainting. It won't prevent view recalculations for each row remove. beginResetModel is made for such operations

Comment: I know, but I thought this maybe can help if the tree is really large. I understand that beingResetModel is the right way to do this now. Thanks.